# Oracle SQL Developer - Database Copy/Database Diff grayed out

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer version 19.2, when i pinpoint to "Tools", options "Database Copy" and "Database Diff" are grayed out. 
How to enable them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the Tools -> Database Copy and Database Diff options to be enabled, at least two connections must already be defined in SQL Developer.